# IntelliJ IDEA - Remove empty line at End of File using hot keys

Tags: intellij-idea

Am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.3 on macOS Catalina 10.15.4.

Trying to figure out how to NOT have an empty line when I conduct a <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> via the hot keys.

Unformatted:

[image: Unformatted File]

---

After conducting <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>, its still unformatted (lines 10 and 11 are still visible):

[image]

---

This is what I am seeking after issuing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>:

[image]

---

As you can see, I do not want an empty line / newline inserted after the last closing `}` brace of a Java class.

Comment: Do you have [this option](https://i.imgur.com/D8iYkWM.png) enabled?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - No, its not checked / enabled.

Comment: Note that having a newline at the last line of text is a good thing in Unix for using command-line tools etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [an option to enforce an empty line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G04of.png) at the end of file, but [there is no the opposite option at the moment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119281).

If this option exists in any third-party formatters, you could try a plug-in or an external tool that will apply it (like [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter)).

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder - from the YouTrack Issue URL which you provided, why hasn't this been addressed? It was created nearly six years ago! How to escalate this?

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover I've increased the issue priority.